# Network WiFi connection options

Tags: wireless-networking

I have the option to connect with either 2.4GHz or 5GHz wireless connections, or even both. Would selecting 2.4GHz and 5GHz connections and having both open at the same time, cause problems operating my computer?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are referring to.  In this case I assume you mean the 2.4GHz and 5GHz connections.  I would edit your question to make that clear for everyone.

Comment: You should also clarify what you want to connect with each other. Most clients can not be connected to both frequencies at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to connect to both of these wifi signals at the same time, unless your device has more than one network card inside it.

As for which one you want to connect too, 5ghz is the newer standard available from 802.11n and above. The reason it is there is because in crowded areas with lots of signals the wifi quality can deteriorate when there are lots of different access points nearby (think an apartment block where everyone has their own wifi router). By moving from 2.4 to 5ghz you are on a whole new wavelength and other peoples signal won't clash with yours. However in a non crowded area you won't notice a difference between them.

The reason that 2.4ghz is still offered is that many older devices aren't compatible with the new 5ghz wifi.

Comment: Actually, what you wrote, "_5ghz is the newer standard,_" is not all that new. The 802.11a Wi-Fi using 5 GHz was approved September 1999, the same month that the 2.4 GHz 802.11b was approved , and many older Wi-Fi devices use 5 GHz, too. It's only that 802.11b devices were cheaper, and therefore more popular among the mass consumers. The newest frequency is 60 GHz for 802.11ad.